# Flutter dynamic size 3D button

Tags: flutter, user-interface, button, 3d, widget

I'm trying to implement next buttons and I want to have a single widget that accepts `child`, `color` and `onTap`.

[image]

The code I've come to so far is next:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';

const darkGreyColor = Color(0xFFC1C1C1);
const greyColor = Color(0xFFE3E3E3);

class ButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Color color;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  final double height;
  final double width;
  const ButtonWidget(
      {super.key,
      required this.height,
      required this.width,
      required this.color,
      required this.child,
      required this.onTap});

  @override
  State<ButtonWidget> createState() => _ButtonWidgetState();
}

class _ButtonWidgetState extends State<ButtonWidget> {
  static const double _shadowHeight = 4;
  double _position = 4;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) {
        if (widget.onTap == null) {
          return;
        }
        setState(() => _position = _shadowHeight / 2);
      },
      onTapUp: (_) {
        setState(() => _position = _shadowHeight);
        widget.onTap?.call();
      },
      onTapCancel: () => setState(() => _position = _shadowHeight),
      child: Container(
          height: widget.height,
          width: widget.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius:
                  BorderRadius.circular(widget.height + _shadowHeight)),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: Container(
                  height: widget.height,
                  width: widget.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: widget.onTap == null
                          ? darkGreyColor
                          : widget.color.withOpacity(0.5),
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(widget.height))),
                  child: widget.child,
                ),
              ),
              AnimatedPositioned(
                curve: Curves.easeIn,
                bottom: _position,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 50),
                child: AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 50),
                  height: _position == _shadowHeight / 2
                      ? widget.height - _shadowHeight
                      : widget.height,
                  width: _position == _shadowHeight / 2
                      ? widget.width - _shadowHeight
                      : widget.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: widget.onTap == null ? greyColor : widget.color,
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(widget.height))),
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      widget.child,
                      Positioned(
                          top: widget.height / 16,
                          left: widget.height / 8,
                          child: AnimatedOpacity(
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 50),
                              opacity: _position == _shadowHeight / 2 ? 0 : 1,
                              child:
                                  SvgPicture.asset('assets/button_blick.svg')))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

It works great, because I have strict height and width. However the size can change based on localization. Detecting text width & height will not work because Icon can be provided as child as well. Also app will support smartphones and tablets, which will be dynamically scaled. I tried `IntrinsicWidth` - works fine but height need to be provided. Same for `IntrinsicHeight`.

Any ideas?

P.S. ChatGPT sucks in this case.